# .replace is skipped during a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I want to convert a `.data` file to a `.csv` file, therefore I am reading the `.data` file in, replacing some characters and strings, so that the `.csv` file should be readable with [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). Unfortunately the two lines:

```
line = line.replace("yes", "1") 
line = line.replace("no", "0")
```

are skipped. So the `.loadtxt` function wont work. I was trying to change the characters of the replacement, everything without success. Would be nice if someone could help me. Here is the full code:

```
import numpy as np

fString = open("diagnosis.data", "r")
fFloat = open("diagnosis.csv", "w")

for line in fString:
    line = line.replace(",", ".")
    line = line.replace("\t", ",")
    line = line.replace("yes", ",1")
    line = line.replace("no", "0")
    line = line.replace("\r\n", "\n")
    fFloat.write(line)

fString.close()
fFloat.close()

fFloat = open("diagnosis.csv","r")
dataset = np.loadtxt(fFloat, delimiter=",")
fFloat.close()
```

---

The dataset can be found [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Acute+Inflammations)

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that may be wrong is your line reference is not rewriting fString. You could try something closer to this syntax? This will actually modify fString as opposed to just the line variable.

```
for line in range(fString):
    fString[line] = fString[line].replace(",", ".")
```